# Can ing nouns substitute the already existing ones?

Tags: word-difference, suffixes

When there is an existing noun (as memorization) could we use the *ing* to form another one (memorizing)?

If so, what would be the difference between the two concurrent nouns?

Comment: As a noun, I think ***memorizing*** is hardly used. It is much more common to use ***memorization***.

Comment: In this specific case, yes.  The gerund form, _"memorizing,"_ **is** used (as a noun, because that's what gerunds do.) I disagree that _memorization_ is "much more common."  Here is some evidence to the contrary: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+memorizing%2C+like+memorization&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20memorizing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20memorization%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Adam the n-gram graph is not enough because if you look closely (I checked the first page) you would notice that majority of hits for *memorizing* are not noun, they are verb.

Comment: @Adam Please perdon me, but it's not correct. In all your sentences except the first sentence, *memorizing* is not a noun, it's a verb. And I agree that the first sentence is not wrong, but it's more common to use *memorization* in place of *memorizing*, IMO.

Comment: @Man_From_India  I don't know which page you mean by "first," but I see things like _"Memorizing of good poetry should be made a pleasure..."_ and _"It would be like memorizing the demonstration of one of Euclid's theorems..."_  and _"Studying for a math test is just like memorizing the rules"_ and _"I don't like memorizing poetry,"_  All of those examples of _"memorizing"_ are gerunds in gerund phrases, acting as nouns.

Comment: @Man_From_India Are you saying that in constructions like _"I don't like memorizing poetry,"_ **memorizing** is a verb?

Comment: @Adam yes. It's indeed a verb there.

Comment: @Adam There's a confusion at whether you see a **gerund** or a **verb+ing** before you. Take an example: **"I like flying"** - Is it **what?** or **doing what?**

Comment: _I am flying_ - participle. _I like flying_ - gerund.  How do we know it is a gerund, not a verb?  Because it is acting as a noun - namely, it is the direct object of the actual verb in the sentence, _like._  That's what gerunds are - verbals formed with ing that occupying the places in sentences where verbs don't go.  https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/01/  or https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-8/verbals-and-phrases/lesson-5/gerunds-and-gerund-phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes. You can either use **memorization** or **memorising** as a noun. However, when there already exists a noun that carries the meaning you wish to infer I would recommend you use it:

- The growing of plants is an exciting thing to research.
- The growth of plants is an exciting thing to research.

Comment: Can you supply a reference that supports your assertion that *"Verb+ing"* acting as the subject of a sentence is not a gerund?

Comment: @Adam Well that statement is plain wrong, but I see no such claim in his answer :-O strange!

Comment: @Adam Check my edit.

Comment: _"...selling different things"_ is still a gerund phrase, and _selling_ is still a gerund.  It seems like you are wanting to distinguish gerunds on their own from gerunds that have complements/modifiers/etc, but that distinction isn't correct.  _I like flying.  I like flying quickly.  I like flying with my dog.  I like flying to the moon.  I like flying on airplanes."_  In all of these examples, _flying_ is a gerund, with or without modifiers and complements.  A non-gerund use would look like  _"I am flying to the moon."_  Here _flying_ is part of the main verb of the sentence.

Comment: @Adam **selling** in my second sentence is a verb in the Present Continuous tense.

Comment: No it isn't.  Your second sentence is   `[ Someone ] + [Likes] + [Something]` The verb is _like._ The present continuous tense would be `[Subject] + [is doing] (+ [Something])` _"I **am selling** different things."_

Comment: @Adam You wish to say that in: **I like bringing him new toys.** the word **"bringing"** is a gerund?

Comment: Yep.  `A:` _I like some things._  `B:` _What things do you like?_ `A:` _I like my family.  I like my brother.  I like bringing him toys._  The verb is _like_ in all three cases.  This website has many more examples: http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_same_list.htm The entire left column is gerunds.

Comment: @Adam I am really confused. Since **a gerund** is a noun but in your examples it is a verb everywhere. As I understand **I like flying in an airplane** is a **verb+ing** and **I like to fly in an airplane** is a **bare infinitive**. But **The flying made me sick** here **flying** is a gerund because it acts as a noun and answers the question **What?** and not **Doing what?** You can have two and sometimes even three verbs following each other.

Comment: _"...in your examples it is a verb everywhere."_   It isn't, though.  It is a noun.  You seem to think that **verb+ing** means that it isn't a gerund.  Gerunds are one of the things you can end up with if you add **ing** to a verb.  You can also end up with a participle, and the only way to tell the difference is how it is used.  If it is used with an auxiliary verb it is a participle: *I am skiing.*  If it is used in a place in the sentence where we might otherwise use a noun, then it IS a noun, and we call it a gerund: _**Skiing** is dangerous.  **Eating** peaches makes my eyes water."

Comment: I note that on this page: http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_list.htm _doing_ is used as an example of a gerund. `Q:` _He delayed **doing** what?_  `A:` _He delayed **doing** his taxes._

Comment: Sovereign, your last edit ruined your answer. This line - *there is no difference between the noun and the gerund* - is to blame. Gerund is a verb-form that can sometimes be treated as an equivalent of a noun. But a noun and a verb are not the same. For example, - *I like flying in the jetplane*. Here *fly* and *flying* are the different word-form of the same lexeme - *fly*. It's no other than a verb. Well, you can call this *flying* in this sentence a Gerundial-Noun. In *he loves flying kites*, this *flying* is also a verb, but not equivalent to a noun by any means. (Cont...)

Comment: (Cont...) You can call it Gerund Participle form of verb.

Answer (score 3):

Native speakers often use **memorizing** as a noun:

> Understanding how these chemical processes work involves far more than
>   memorizing. Memorization is required, to be sure, but memorizing alone doesn't lead to understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Memorize is a verb, as in "He memorized his address."

Memorization a noun describing the process of committing something to memory.

Memorizing is already in use as a gerund or present participle of "to memorize." As in, "She is memorizing the lecture notes." Memorizing isn't used as a noun.

Comment: _"Memorizing is already in use as a gerund .....Memorizing isn't used as a noun."_
 That's what gerunds are - verbs being used as nouns.